# rsync mechanism in wso2 all in one active-active

Tags: configuration, wso2, rsync, wso2-api-manager

I am deploying active-active all in one in 2 separate servers with wso2-am 2.6.0 and wso2 analytics 2.6.0. I am configuring my servers by [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment#ConfiguringanActive-ActiveDeployment-Step5). In part 4 and 5 about rsync mechanism I have some questions:
1.how can I figure out that my server is working rsync or sync??
2.What will happen in future if I don't use rsync now and also don't use configuration on part 4 and 5 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1.how can I figure out that my server is working rsync or sync??

It is not really clear what are you asking for.. rsync is just a command to synchronize files in folders.

What is the rsync used for - when deploying an API, the gateway creates or updates a few synapse sequences or apis in the filesystem (repository/deployment/server) and these file updates need to be synchronized to all gateway nodes.

I personally don't advice using rsync, the whole issue is that you need to invoke regularly the `rsync`command to synchronize the files created by a master node. That creates certain delay for service availability and most important, if something goes wrong and you want to use another node as the master, you need to switch the rsync direction, which is not really automated process.

We usually keep it simple using a shared filesystem (nfs, gluster, ..) and then we have all active-active setup (ok, setting up HA NFS or glusterFS is not particulary simple, but that's usually job of the infra guys)

> 2.What will happen in future if I don't use rsync now and also don't use configuration on part 4 and 5 ?

In the case the filesystems between gateways is not synced or shared - you deploy an api from the publisher to a single gateway node, but other gateway nodes won't create the synapse sequences and api artefacts. As a result the other nodes won't pass the client request to the backend

Comment: thanks, according to your response I preferred to not use rsync. If I use another shared filesystem (nfs, gluster, ..) so I don't need to use part 4 and 5 configuration hints in [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment#ConfiguringanActive-ActiveDeployment-Step2-Configuretheloadbalancer) ? Am I right?

Comment: @N.Abdolalizade if you are using a shared FS for the server (repository/deployment/server) and an all-in-one instance (no separate gateway), you don't need to do anything